# Cancel a work item started with ThreadPool.RunAsync

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have the following code:

```
var op = ThreadPool.RunAsync(delegate { _model.HeapSort(); });
```

Is there a way to stop this thread, for example when I push a "Cancel" button? I have tried `op.Cancel()` but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Assuming `HeapSort` doesn't implement cancellation as well, not really, no.

Comment: You'll have the exact same problem there too, for the exact same reason.

Comment: So is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Have an implementation of `HeapSort` that provides cooprative cancellation, i.e. accepts a `CancellationToken` and checks it periodically.  The only other real alternative is to have the code continue moving on to doing whatever is "next" even though the sorting isn't actually done, which isn't technically cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation of HeapSort, there must be a flag to stop the current thread.

If you are doing a loop for example:

```
while(!cancelThread)
{
   ... // Your iterative sort algorithm here
}
```

Then if you set that **cancelThread** variable to **true**, then your Thread will end. `CancellationToken` structure is used for this kind of thread control.

Comment: `CancellationToken` isn't *just* a boolean flag though.  Most important it ensures the proper synchronization techniques such that marking the token as cancelled will actually be "realized" when it's read from another thread.  This is an easy thing to overlook when just using a regular `bool` and can cause pretty major problems.

Comment: @Servy, that is right. Just giving the idea, you know.

Answer (score 0):

`ThreadPool.RunAsync` accepts a delegate of type `WorkItemHandler`:

```
public delegate void WorkItemHandler(IAsyncAction operation)
```

Its only argument `IAsyncAction` is derived from `IAsyncInfo`. There's [`IAsyncInfo.Status`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.iasyncinfo.status.aspx) property. I presume it's set to `AsyncStatus.Canceled` when `IAsyncInfo.Cancel` is called (untested).

So, you could check periodically if `operation.Status == AsyncStatus.Canceled` inside your delegate, and throw `OperationCancelledException`.